# Shuffle the items based on order

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of items in c#, need to shuffle the items based on the below format. if possible to do the same in Linq Query?

```
Input Sample data
    **Frouts**
    Orange
    Orange
    Orange
    Orange
    Mango
    Mango
    Mango
    Mango
    Mango
    Mango
    Apple
    Apple
    Apple
```

I required following Out put

```
**Frouts**
    Orange
    Mango
    Apple
    Orange
    Mango
    Apple
    Orange
    Mango
    Apple
    Orange
    Mango
    Mango
    Mango
```

Comment: I fail to see any connection in the order of the required output. Please explain some more.

Comment: As @Matthijs says there is no mind reading service available that tell us why your output is what you say it should be. And without the code we can't see what is causing it to be wrong. You have written some code eh?

Comment: You should explain better, your list contains only Oranges, Mango and Apples?

Comment: Going out on a limb here: Do you want to group the three types of `fruit`: `Orange, Mango, Apple` in that order; for as many times as possible, and put the trailing fruits that can not be grouped at the end?

Comment: we have only once column in List like above needs to shuffle.

Comment: It's a not a shuffle, shuffle (to me at least) means totally random order. I guess the OP means: there's a set of `n` unique items {n1, n2, n3, ... nn}, and another set of instance all drawn from it (e.g. {n1, n3, n3, n2, n5, n4, ...}), rearrange them so it goes through the unique items as evenly as possible?

Comment: Did you try and solve this yourself? And per comment from Matthijs... what exactly is the connection between the input and the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do what you want, and gives the output you specified:

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>
{
    "Orange",
    "Orange",
    "Orange",
    "Orange",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Apple",
    "Apple",
    "Apple"
};

var groupedStrings = listOfStrings.GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(i => new {i.Key, Items = i.ToList()}).ToList();

var maxGroupSize = groupedStrings.OrderByDescending(i => i.Items.Count).First()
    .Items.Count;

var finalList = new List<string>();

for (var i = 0; i < maxGroupSize; i++)
{
    finalList.AddRange(from wordGroup in groupedStrings 
                        where i < wordGroup.Items.Count 
                        select wordGroup.Items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check my ShuffleProject in Github.

You will be able to shuffle Lists where T is what you want, and arrays easily.

You will be able to find the code, and the .dll if you want to use it in your project.

https://github.com/Oscarbralo/ShuffleProject

But generally, you can use something like this!

```
public List<T> Shuffle(List<T> objects, int totalElements)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            List<T> resultList = new List<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
            {
                int maxElements = objects.Count - 1;
                int randomElement = random.Next(0, maxElements);
                resultList.Add(objects[randomElement]);
                objects.RemoveAt(randomElement);
            }
            return resultList;
        }
```

I hope this helps